# How to show/hide block depending on url in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The application has two buttons for selecting an action. I need to make sure that when you select a specific action, a specific url is set and a block appears or hides. I've tried to use $scope.watch and $location methods, but I don't know what to add next.
I've got experience with Angular 2+ and there is router snapshot and so on. AngularJS is a bit different in this field.

template.html

```html
    <button ng-click="setVal('block1')">Show block 1</button>
    <button ng-click="setVal('block2')">Show block 2</button>

    <div ng-if="showBlock == 'block1'">block 1</div>
    <div ng-if="showBlock == 'block2">block 2</div>
```

Controller.js

```js
    module.exports = angular
      .module('page.main', [])
      .controller('MainCtrl', ($scope, $location) => {
        'ngInject';

        $scope.showBlock = null;

        // controller to url

        $scope.$watch((newVal) => {
          console.log('Property changed!');
          $location.search('showBlock', newVal);
        });
        
        // url to controller

        $scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (event) {
          console.log("URL changed!");
          self['showBlock'] = $location.search()['showBlock'];
        });

        $scope.setVal = (val) => {
          $scope.showBlock = val;
          return $scope.showBlock;
        };
      });
```

Comment: This `<button ng-click="setVal("block1")">` doesn't look like it'll work as expected; you're probably going to need to use single quotes here for the inner argument

Comment: thanks, you're right